# Как получить номер элемента в linq?

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть список объектов linq
Объект:

```
{id, count}
```

Они расположены по возрастанию count, как я могу получить номер объекта в этом списке по id?

```
List<Route> routes = _applicationDbContext.Routes.OrderBy(a =>a.count).ToList();
```

- Список отсортирован (что из себя представляет объект чуть выше)
- Нужно получить порядковый номер объекта по id
- Ответ это число, порядковый номер элемента

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Проведите пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат

Comment: @АндрейNOP Надеюсь сейчас стало легче понять, что я говорю

Comment: Что такое порядковый номер? Порядковый номер в этом отсортированном списке?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count; ++i) if (routes[i].Id == id) index = i;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, как я понимаю, это можно сделать с помощью linq, а не простым перебором
Да, это порядковый номер в отсортированном списке

Comment: `.TakeWhile(r => r.id != id).Count()` — чисто Linq-вариант с одним проходом. Но я бы не стал использовать это в продакшн, лучше взять готовый метод класса List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен "индекс", так? Если да, то для этого у `List<>` есть такие методы, как `IndexOf()` или вовсе `FindIndex()`, которые сделают за вас все необходимое.

К примеру у нас есть такой класс:

```
class Item
{
    public Item(int id, int count)
    {
        Id = id;
        Count = count;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Мы делаем коллекцию:

```
var testList = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1002, 55),
    new Item(1001, 454),
    new Item(1003, 754)
};
```

Сортируем:

```
var sortList = testList.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Ну и дальше 3 варианта:

1. С помощью `IndexOf()`:

   ```
   var listIndex = sortList.IndexOf(sortList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1002));
   ```

   Как видите коротко и довольно просто, достаточно всего лишь получить нужный объект. Если же надо при помощи LINQ, то там придется немного городить...
2. Полностью на `LINQ`:

   ```
   var linqIndex = sortList.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.item.Id == 1002).index;
   ```

   Тут как видите чуть длиннее строка, ибо нам надо делать лишнее действие - составить список `{index, item}` и уже потом получить нужный индекс.
3. Еще один вариант на чистом `LINQ` (спасибо @АндрейNOP):

   ```
   var whileIndex = sortList.TakeWhile(r => r.Id != 1002).Count();
   ```

   Берем элементы до тех пор, пока условие будет истинно и после считаем их кол-во, которое и будет нужным индексом.
4. Ну и самое простое, `FindIndex()` (но и самое правильное):

   ```
   var findIndex = sortList.FindIndex(x => x.Id == 1002);
   ```

Все варианты нам в итоге дадут число 1.

Как правильно заметил в комментариях @АндрейNOP - все способы имеют свой недостаток и лучше использовать `FindIndex()`, ибо он выдаст с минимальными затратами нужный нам результат, хотя это и не является LINQ.

Comment: Надо заметить, что первый вариант делает два прохода по списку, второй создаёт кучу лишних объектов. Третий способ хорош и нужно использовать именно его, но это не Linq, конечно, это готовый метод класса List

Comment: @EvgeniZ Спасибо